# Add one to return value?

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
testFunc as (b:bs) 
          | b `elem` as = testFunc as bs + 1
          | otherwise   = testFunc as bs
```

If the head of the second argument (`bs`) is not an element of the list in the first argument (`a`), the function is invoked recursively, and +1 is added to the end result. However, what I don't understand, is how this addition of 1 is possible. After all, the function only takes two arguments?

Comment: This is parsed as `(testFunc as bs) + 1`, function application binds more tightly than all operators in terms of order of operations.

Comment: In general, I prefer to add explicit parentheses because it results in safe, readable code. This is especially helpful when you are learning. Consider a function `f :: Int -> Int`. If you see `f x + 1`, Haskell will parse that as `(f x)+1`, but you may have meant it to be parsed as `f (x+1)`, and someone unfamiliar with Haskell wouldn't have any idea which way it would be parsed.

Comment: @Eric, redundant parentheses can be distracting. I generally expect symbols in code to do something; when they don't, I have to stare at them for a moment to realize that I need to filter them out. There are exceptions, of course, but part of learning Haskell is getting used to the syntax for function application and to the fact that it binds more tightly than anything else.

Comment: @dfeuer In my example, `f` and `+` are both functions, so your rule that "functions bind more tightly" doesn't help. The root here is precedence. I've been doing this a long time, and still don't have [this table](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.2) memorized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+ 1` is not another (or two more) arguments to `testFunc`, it is a modification of the value returned by `testFunc`.

It might be easier to view it with parentheses:

```
testFunc as (b:bs) 
      | b 'elem' as = (testFunc as bs) + 1
      | otherwise   = testFunc as bs
```

So in the first case, we make the recursive call, and get a value. Then we add one to it. In the second case, we make a recursive call and then return that value unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

you have to look at the type signature

```
testfunc Num b, Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> b
testfunc _ [] = 0 -- the base case you ommited
testFunc as (b:bs) 
          | b `elem` as = (testFunc as bs) + 1
          | otherwise   = testFunc as bs
```

so you add 1 the result of testfunc (which is a number)